# Sidebar menu close when click elsewhere

Tags: jquery, sidebar

I've got a sidebar navigation menu that toggles when the Menu button is clicked.

I would also like it to close when user clicks away from the sidebar.
I have seen other questions / answers about the same thing but I can't figure out how to apply it to the code I'm using. Also read something about event listeners so that clicking elsewhere is only active when sidebar is open.

```js
$(function () {
  $('.nav-toggle').on('click', function () {
    $('.sideNav').toggleClass('open');
  });
});
```

```css
.sideNav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 3em;
  left: 0;
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: auto;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-100%);
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s ease;
  transition: transform 0.6s ease;
}

.sideNav.open {
  transform: translateX(0);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  -ms-transform: translateX(0);
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div>
  <button class="nav-toggle">Menu</button>
  <nav class="sideNav">
    <ul>
      <li>...</li>
      <li>...</li>
      <li>...</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: please link to the questions you have looked at and explain why you are unable to apply them in your case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(function () {
  $('.nav-toggle').on('click', function (e) {
    $('.sideNav').toggleClass('open');

    e.stopPropagation();
    return false;
  });

  $('*:not(.nav-toggle)').on('click', function () {
    $('.sideNav').removeClass('open');
  });

});
```

Working fiddle:

- https://jsfiddle.net/q907731k/8/

Answer (score 0):

You can play with `target`. An example is something like this:

```js
$(function () {
  
  $('body').on('click', function(event) {
    if(event.target.className == 'nav-toggle') {
      $('.sideNav').addClass('open');
    } else {
      $('.sideNav').removeClass('open');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.sideNav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 3em;
  left: 0;
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: auto;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-100%);
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s ease;
  transition: transform 0.6s ease;
}

.sideNav.open {
  transform: translateX(0);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  -ms-transform: translateX(0);
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div>
  <button class="nav-toggle">Menu</button>
  <nav class="sideNav">
    <ul>
      <li>...</li>
      <li>...</li>
      <li>...</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the event check if the target is this element (side bar) or his childs and if not hide it. Here is something I did use. Hopes it helps.

```
$(document).on("click", function (e) {                          
            var elem, evt = e ? e : event;
            if (evt.srcElement) {
                elem = evt.srcElement;
            }
            else if (evt.target) {
                elem = evt.target;
            }
            if (elem.className !== "sideNav" ) {
                $(".sideNav").css("display", "none");                  
            }
        });

    };
```